# C++ How to call the methods of a template variadic type list inside a method of the class which derived from that list?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

So I want a class which allows a sequence of classes to call their decode/encode methods in that way:

```
/// This class manages the decoding/encoding of a sequence of binary fields.
template <typename Derived, typename... Fields >
struct BinarySequence : Fields...
{
    using Super = BinarySequence;

    bool decode(const char* buffer, size_t& length)
    {
        return true && Fields...::decode(buffer, length);
    }

    bool encode(char* buffer, size_t& length)
    {
        return true && Fields...::encode(buffer, length);
    }
};
```

The issue is to call `Fields...::decode(buffer, length)` is not the correct way. If I have `BinarySequence< MessageType, MessageSender, MessageTimeStamp >`, I want its decoder to do the same as

```
bool decode(const char* buffer, size_t& length)
{
    return MessageType::decode(buffer, length) && MessageSender::decode(buffer, length) && MessageTimeStamp::decode(buffer, length);
}
```

What would be the right way to do so? I use Visual Studio Code 2017.

Comment: it's `return (true && ... && Fields::decode(buffer, length) );`

Comment: `(Fields::decode(buffer, length) && ...)`? (and `true &&` can be removed).

Comment: By the way, there is no such thing as Visual Studio Code 2017 - you either use Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio Code

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact right syntax, and you need to set the C++ standard as C++17 or latest in the compiler settings, but `return (Fields::decode(buffer, length) && ...);` should work

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep but I think I must do `(... && Fields::decode(buffer, length)` if I want to evalue the decode of first class of Fields first (the order matters).

Comment: No, it will always happen left-to-right. `&&` is associative.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
nevermind, I forgot && is always evaluating from left to right so the decode methods of Field1, Field2, ..., FieldN should always be called in that order, which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). The correct syntax is:

```cpp
/// This class manages the decoding/encoding of a sequence of binary fields.
template <typename Derived, typename... Fields >
struct BinarySequence : Fields...
{
    using Super = BinarySequence;

    bool decode(const char* buffer, size_t& length)
    {
        return (Fields::decode(buffer, length) && ...);
    }

    bool encode(char* buffer, size_t& length)
    {
        return (Fields::encode(buffer, length) && ...);
    }
};
```

This requires C++17 or newer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip link. I wasn't sure about the exact name of that expression. From what I read, it must be (... && Fields::decode()) because I need to evaluate the first class in the list first.

Comment: Well, in fact, I'm not really sure: every terminal decode method is advancing buffer and reducing length so the order of the evaluation matters. I guess what you propose should work: (C1::decode && (C2::decode && C3::decode)) because && always evaluates from left to right. Great answer, checking it !

Comment: @hlide For 3 parameters `(... && P)` means `((P1 && P2) && P2)` while `(P && ...)` means `(P1 && (P2 && P3))`